# check username and password input with data stored in text file in c++

Tags: c++

This is my code:

```
`
void Customer::validate_cust_username_and_password()
    {
        string uname, pword;
        cout << "enter name: " << endl;
        cin >> uname;
        cout << "enter password: " << endl;
        cin >> pword;
        ifstream myfile("cust_username_and_password.txt");
        if (myfile.is_open())
        {
            while (!myfile.eof())
            {

                if (uname == cust_username && pword == cust_password)
                {
                    cout << "Login successfully." << endl;
                    cust_mainmenu();
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "Wrong username or password!" << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }

            myfile.close();
        }

    }
`
```

This is another code which store the username and password:

```
  `void Customer::cust_register_name_and_password()
{
    string un, pw;
    ofstream myfile("cust_username_and_password.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
    cout << "Enter Customer Username= " << endl;
    getline(cin, un);
    cout << "Enter Customer Password= " << endl;
    getline(cin, pw);
    myfile << endl << un << "  " << pw << endl;
    myfile.close();

    cout << "Register Successfully." << endl;
    system("pause");
}`
```

So the problem is when I enter the username and password which I already stored in the text file before, the output is only showing the "Wrong username or password!".

Really appreciate if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `validate_cust_username_and_password` function, you never read in the username and password. Add this:

```
 myfile >> cust_username >> cust_password;
```

Comment: If I helped, you can help too by accepting the answer :)

Comment: do u mean vote up @awesomeyi?
I want to, but it say "Vote Up requires 15 reputation"  :(

Answer (score 0):

`cust_username` and `cust_password` are never set anywhere in this code, so they will never match the user's input (unless the user enters empty strings).

Comment: oh sorry, 'cust_username' and 'cust_password' are in my 'class customer', i didn't post the full code here.

Answer (score 0):

```
    string uname, pword;
    cout << "enter name: " << endl;
    cin >> uname;
    cout << "enter password: " << endl;
    cin >> pword;
    ifstream myfile("password.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (!myfile.eof())
        {

            if (uname == "test" && pword == "0000")
            {
                cout << "Login successfully." << endl;
                cust_mainmenu();
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Wrong username or password!" << endl;
                break;
            }
        }

        myfile.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)

Answer (score -1):

Where did  `cust_username` magically appear. Was Paul Daniels involved. Paul I take that back you are not as bad as David Blaine - but not a lot

Comment: oh sorry, 'cust_username' is on my 'class customer', i didn't post the full code here.